# Weekly total change name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have made a view on Microsoft sql server  for sum by week this is the sql code

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(ww, D_Date), 101) AS ReportingWeek,      Proj_name, SUM(Expr1) AS total
FROM     dbo.View_Test_Two
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, DATEPART(ww, D_Date), 101), Proj_name
ORDER BY ReportingWeek
```

every thing is just okay , **but my problem is with the week names**

---

- 27    data 330736
- 28    data 117868
- 29    data 471472
- 31    data 246468

**now i need to make instead of 27,28,29,31 something like week 1 , week 2 , week 3...etc**

..
*thank you in advance .*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT 'week ' + CONVERT(varchar(255), DATEPART(ww, D_Date) - 26) AS ReportingWeek,
       Proj_name, SUM(Expr1) AS total
FROM  dbo.View_Test_Two
GROUP BY DATEPART(ww, D_Date), Proj_name
ORDER BY min(D_Date);
```

Comment: what if i want separate each month... i mean each month start with 1 till 4 then start over in next month

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would use the mod operator `%`.